# Delphi : How to send text to one specific client connected to the server socket knowing their local IP Address?

Tags: sockets, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm working on a small text-based messaging platform over the network for my IT class.

Everything works, but now I'm trying to implement a private message function where you essentially enter your friend's IP and the message, and that gets sent to the server and it is able to send the message to the specific client related to that IP.

I have everything working, except I'm not able to figure out how to send text to one specific client based on their IP address. I thought I would be able to do this where `temp2` is a string and `msgIP` is the target IP and `msg` is the message:

```
for I := 1 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections do
begin
  temp2:=ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i];
  if temp2=msgIP then
  begin
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i].SendText(msg);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three mistakes in your code:

1. The `Connections[]` property uses 0-based indexes, but your loop is using 1-based indexes.  You will always skip the first connection, and crash trying to access past the last connection.
2. the `Connections[]` property returns a `TCustomWinSocket` object pointer, not a string.  You need to compare the target IP string to the object's `RemoteAddress` property value.
3. you are not breaking the loop if you find a match.

Try this instead:

```
var
  client: TCustomWinSocket;
begin
  for I := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    client := ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i];
    if client.RemoteAddress = msgIP then
    begin
      client.SendText(msg);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now, with that said, know that the `RemoteAddress` is the remote client's IP from the server's perspective.  If the client is connecting to the server through a proxy or NAT/router, the `RemoteAddress` IP will be that of the proxy/NAT, not the client itself.  Multiple clients could be connected through the same proxy/NAT, so they would all have the same `RemoteAddress` IP.  If this is just for a class assignment and there is no proxy/NAT involved, then `RemoteAddress` may be fine, provided you don't have multiple instances of your app running on the same machine at the same time.

To uniquely identify a specific client on the server, regardlesss of how it is connected to the server, you need to use the client's `RemoteAddress` **and** `RemotePort` property values together:

```
var
  client: TCustomWinSocket;
begin
  for I := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    client := ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i];
    if (client.RemoteAddress = msgIP) and (client.RemotePort = msgPort) then
    begin
      client.SendText(msg);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, using IP+Port is not very intuitive when one client wants to communicate with another client, especially if they do not know each other's Port values.

A better option is to have each client login to the server with a unique identifier, such as a username.  You can use the client's `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property to keep track of per-client data and compare it as needed, eg:

```
type
  TClientData = record
    UserName: string;
  end;

...

// during login...
var
  ClientData: TClientData;
begin
  New(ClientData);
  ClientData.UserName := ...; // read from the client
  Socket.Data := ClientData;
end;

...

// during logout/disconnect...
var
  ClientData: TClientData;
begin
  ClientData := Socket.Data;
  Socket.Data := nil;
  Dispose(ClientData);
end;

...

// during private messaging
var
  client: TCustomWinSocket;
begin
  for I := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    client := ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i];
    if TClientData(client.Data).UserName = msgUser then
    begin
      client.SendText(msg);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This way, you can send messages to a specific client regardless of where it is located and how it is connected to the server.  Especially if the client disconnects and reconnects, where its IP/Port changes per connection.  A login identifier would be more consistent and easier to work with.